# Month abbreviations show 4 characters instead of 3

Tags: c#, date-formatting

I have in code

```
string dateStr = dateTime.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

On my Windows 11 machine instead of "21-Sep-2021" it generates month with 4 character abbreviation “21-Sept-2021”.

It is generated correctly as 3 characters on the server and other developers machines. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.abbreviatedmonthnames?view=net-7.0#property-value

I didn’t find where I can change settings. I  played with settings as suggested in https://pureinfotech.com/change-time-date-windows-11/
But everything looks ok, Localisation shows “English-Australia”

I’ve confirmed that Australia has 3 characters month abbreviation https://lh.2xlibre.net/locale/en_AU/ and on page https://lh.2xlibre.net/values/abmon/ no localization has 4 character months abbreviations.

I am curious which setting can cause this behaviour?

As a workaround I explicitly specified InvariantCulture

```
 dateTime.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: This is indeed interesting. Did you try to change your Windows 11 language to US English?

Comment: Maybe one of those NLS vs. ICU problems. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu

Comment: Means dependent on concrete Win10/Win11 patched versions and/or used framework different sources for those names are used and they might differ.

Comment: What's the actual locale? The short month name is provided by Windows. If the locale uses a 4 instead of 3 letter abbreviation, `dd-MMM-yyyy` will return 4 characters. You can get the current culture with `Thread.CurrentCulture`.

Comment: I found that `dateTime.ToString("MMM",CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE")` returns `Sept` but `dd-MMM-yyyy` returns `21-Sept.-2023`. All German cultures do so. What's the actual culture of the thread and what's the application type? In a web app with culture detection the `Accept-Languages` header can be used to modify the thread's culture

Comment: What's the month abbreviation in Australia? `MMM` stands for the month abbreviation, not just the first 3 letters.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that seems to be the distinction between AbbreviatedMonthNames and AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames from the CultureInfo. If i understood correctly when days(dd) are in the pattern AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames is used in most cultures for month otherwise AbbreviatedMonthNames. Author linked AbbreviatedMonthNames but its presumably not the one used here rather the other.

Comment: @Ralf this almost make sense - AFAIK there's no real genitive in modern English (not a English scholar), but official documents, the ones for which style guides exist, would use the "genitive" form. So if the styles specify a different form, that's where it would be stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually ...... not wrong, although it may not be correct.

From the [Australian Government Style Manual, Dates and time](https://www.stylemanual.gov.au/grammar-punctuation-and-conventions/numbers-and-measurements/dates-and-time)

> The standard abbreviations for the months are:
>
> - ...
> - September –  ‘Sept’
> - ...

On Windows 11, with NET (Core) 8, using dotnet-repl, this script :

```
var dateTime=new DateTime(2023,9,21);
var cults=CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
            .Where(ci=>dateTime.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy",ci)=="21-Sept-2023");
foreach(var cult in cults)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",cult.Name,cult.DisplayName);
}
```

Produces

```
en-AU English (Australia)
en-GB English (United Kingdom)
```

`MMM` is the specifier for the month abbreviation, not just the first three letters of a month, just as `MMMM` is the specifier for the full name.

Windows is used by end users, not just developers, so I suspect there were bugs filed that Windows applications don't produce the official abbreviations, even if they aren't the most common ones used in a country.

I've seen similar questions about `en-ZA` (South Africa) and `en-ZW` (Zimbabwe). In at least one case both `.` and `,` were used as digit separators. One official, one not.